# Convert content from array to hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have the arrangement within an arrangement that is as follows:

```
data = [
  [{
    :devicetotal => "ACH-EPN-AN01",
    :porttotal => "to_BTS IP-CAC HUARAZ - TAI5670",
    :queueIdtotal => "3",
    :device_int_stats_total => "ACH-EPN-AN01to_BTS IP-CAC HUARAZ - TAI56703",
    :timeCapturedtotal => "March 15, 2018 at 07:06 PM",
    :discard_sub => 0
  }],
  [{
    :devicetotal => "ACH-EPN-AN01",
    :porttotal => "to_BTS IP-CAC HUARAZ - TAI5670",
    :queueIdtotal => "6",
    :device_int_stats_total => "ACH-EPN-AN01to_BTS IP-CAC HUARAZ - TAI56706",
    :timeCapturedtotal => "March 15, 2018 at 07:06 PM",
    :discard_sub => 0
  }]
]
```

How do I have the following format?

```
data = [{
  :devicetotal => "ACH-EPN-AN01",
  :porttotal => "to_BTS IP-CAC HUARAZ - TAI5670",
  :queueIdtotal => "3",
  :device_int_stats_total => "ACH-EPN-AN01to_BTS IP-CAC HUARAZ - TAI56703",
  :timeCapturedtotal => "March 15, 2018 at 07:06 PM",
  :discard_sub => 0
}, {
  :devicetotal => "ACH-EPN-AN01",
  :porttotal => "to_BTS IP-CAC HUARAZ - TAI5670",
  :queueIdtotal => "6",
  :device_int_stats_total => "ACH-EPN-AN01to_BTS IP-CAC HUARAZ - TAI56706",
  :timeCapturedtotal => "March 15, 2018 at 07:06 PM",
  :discard_sub => 0
}]
```

I used the following code but I get an error.

```
data2 = Array.new []
data.each do |traf_sub|
  data2 << traf_sub[1]
end
```

Comment: Please edit the question to make it readable without a horizontal scrolling.

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to access index 1 on an array that only has one element. This is also why you should post error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `flatten`

```
data.flatten
#=>  [{:devicetotal=>"ACH-EPN-AN01", :porttotal=>"to_BTS IP-CAC HUARAZ - TAI5670", :queueIdtotal=>"3", :device_int_stats_total=>"ACH-EPN-AN01to_BTS IP-CAC HUARAZ - TAI56703", :timeCapturedtotal=>"March 15, 2018 at 07:06 PM", :discard_sub=>0}, {:devicetotal=>"ACH-EPN-AN01", :porttotal=>"to_BTS IP-CAC HUARAZ - TAI5670", :queueIdtotal=>"6", :device_int_stats_total=>"ACH-EPN-AN01to_BTS IP-CAC HUARAZ - TAI56706", :timeCapturedtotal=>"March 15, 2018 at 07:06 PM", :discard_sub=>0}]
```